# Syntax highlighting broken in vscode (JS)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Suddenly, my syntax highlighting appears to be specifically broken for .js files. Python, and .vue files seem to work fine. I'm on
a new M1 macbook, and I've tried updating to the latest vscode, switching to vanilla color themes, nothing works, anything else I can try?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're in JS language mode?

Comment: Does it happen to JS only?

Answer (score 5):

I found this VSCode extension broke the syntax highlighting after updating.

[image]

I have disabled it and everything works well now.